# Stealing in Mutants and Masterminds

Tags: powers, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

In a question on reddit, someone asked about how to create a Power that replicated the common cartoon trope of a villain holding an item only to not notice (until they try to use it) that it has been stolen by the hero.

The top-rated comment on that proposes the following power:

> What Gun? You Mean This Gun? (15pp total)
>
> - Ranged Teleport Attack 1 Resisted by Dodge, Limited to Disarm Only
>     (2pp)
> - Enhanced Strength 10, Limited to Disarm Only (10pp)
> - Enhanced Advantage - Improved Disarm (1pp)
> - Subtle 2 - Unnoticable (2pp)

There seems to be some disagreement as to whether that's a valid build for it.

Is this an appropriate power for the desired effect?  If not, what would be a good way to replicate it?

Comment: Your question is soliciting opinions about a proposed power, and better ways to generate the desired effect. That's subjective - there are at least three ways to model any effect in M&M3, and which is "best" is a matter of taste and style.

Comment: @ValhallaGH - more correctly, I'm asking if the suggested build is a legal way to do it, and for other ways it can be done.  I'm quite familiar with there being multiple ways to do things in M&M.

Comment: I would probably say you'd need Insidious if you didn't want the villain to realize they been disarmed (effect versus appearance in terms of hiding the attack).

Comment: @Jeff: Is there anything more you'd like in an answer? :)

Answer (score 3):

By the book, as best I can tell, there's no provision for using Teleport to disarm people. [Move Object](http://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/effects/effect-descriptions/move-object-control/) does have provisions to do that, or you could use some form of [Elongation](http://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/effects/effect-descriptions/elongation-general/). Both might suffer from Range penalties depending on your GM, and both will likely need Subtle to avoid being noticed being performed, as well as Insidious to avoid the target from realizing the result. Alternately, one could consider this to be a more difficult [Sleight of Hand](http://www.d20herosrd.com/4-skills#TOC-STEALING) check to steal something someone is holding, probably at least a DC 30, with a bonus to the other person's Perception check to realize they've been stolen from.